# trying to get the member details does not paid by due day

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, datetime, date

I have  a

```
      member table
           member_Id
           member_lastname
           member_firstname

      membership table
            membership_id
            member_id
            membershipoption_Id
            membership_startdate  (values like 2011-09-08,2011-05-06,2011-08-09)
            membership_enddate     (values like 2012-04-05 , 2013-09-08,2014-09-08)
            membership_due day   ( values like only day not including month and year  like 01,21,19,14)

        membershipoption table
                 membershipoption_Id
                 membershipoption_name ( values like 12 months,36 months,24 months)
                 membershipoption_period(values like month ,year)
                 membershipoption_length(12months , 2 years like...)
                 membership_chargeperperiod(53.00,400.00,100.00)
```

is it possible to get the memberdetails who has not paid the money by due day by using above columns ... can any hav idea about this.. many thanks....

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible.  There is no place in that schema to store when, or if, anyone has paid.  Therefore it's not possible to see who has not paid.

Comment: do i need to add any fields to database for getting the overdue members(who has not paid the money by due day)

Comment: I don't know.  Is it your schema/design?  If so, how do you intend to store if, and when, members have paid?  Or is that stored already?  You can't "get" data from the database if it isn't there

Comment: it does not stored in data base but its need to be calculated....i dont want to store in database i want to display member details who has not paid by due day

Comment: It's hard to answer because you're not telling me how you intend to store the fact that a user has paid.  For example: 1. Member pays // 2. Someone updates the database? OR 2. A web service method is called OR 2. Some app checks the bank account and updates the database .. OR .. ? What is the *real-world* process that happens when a member pays?

Comment: by using the membership start date to present date and  he has paid monthly and he has to paid by due date .....

Comment: That is not a real-world process.  Imagine a member hands you some cash, some physical money.  How do you intend to tell the system that that happened?

Answer (score 0):

You need another table with the payment details.
With the information posted, you know when somebody has to pay, but you don't have the information when somebody really payd. Like Kieren Johnstone already posted, it is not possible with that information.